# Need solr to skip very common words

Tags: php, solr, keyword, solarium

I am using solr in my application and want it to ignore some of trivial search queries like "a", "an", "the" etc. I want it to return nothing if it encounters such query strings. Is there anything like dictionary or knowledge base that I can configure with the words that I feel trivial. Or any other suggestion? 
Is my question somehow related with solr stop words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop Words filter is exactly what you need, you should define it for query and index. SOLR comes with ready to use stopwords, but you can extend with anything you want.

Comment: Great.. I will try it out